# Unable to bind ComboBox SelectedValue property with object property

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, combobox

I am tring to bind comboBox `SelectedValue` property with one of my `class property`, here is code for it

```
  ComboBox1.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", _bindingClass, "ID",true);
  //Also tried
  ComboBox1.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", _bindingClass, "ID");
```

Class object structure like this:

```
public class BindingClass
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Here is code for ccomboBox binding

```
   public static void BindDataSourceWithCombo(ref ComboBox cmb)
    {
        DataTable _tableSource = (new AccessConnectionManager()).GetDataTableBySQLQuery("select ValueID,ValueName from PicklistValues");

        var _dataSource = (from DataRow _row in _tableSource.Rows
                           select new
                           {
                               ValueMember = _row["ValueID"],
                               DisplayMember = _row["ValueName"].ToString()

                           }).ToList();

        cmb.DataSource = _dataSource;
        cmb.ValueMember = "ValueMember";
        cmb.DisplayMember = "DisplayMember";
    }
```

ComboBox has `ValueMember` as `int` and `DisplayMember` as `string`.

But its not working, as soon as I leave comboBox display text set to empty and no value display on comboBox.

**EDIT**

When I search for DataType of `ValueID` in Database I found it is `Int16` and in class property I was assigning it with `Int64`. After changing dataType of `ID` property problem get solve.

Comment: What is the DataSource for the ComboBox?  Where is it getting it's *Items* collection from?

Comment: Also, `ComboBox has ValueMember as int and DisplayMember as string.` makes no sense.  ValueMember and DisplayMember refer to the names of Properties, not to their "types".

Comment: @LarsTech Check now I updated my que which will give u clear idea about what I meant to say

Comment: Works for me.  What are the values of your _bindingClass object?  Any other events associated with the ComboBox?

Comment: @LarsTech _bindingClass has value what ever value comes in SelectedValue of combo box, as user change it value of combo box value change for bindingClass, here value is getting set for bindingClass as selectedValue change but when I tab out control it comboBox shows none of any values in list i.e. Its get empty again. Also none of event binded for this combo box

Comment: What is the datatype of `ValueID` from your query `select ValueID,ValueName from PicklistValues`?

Comment: @gannaway Exactly, I was missmatching dataType of class property and Source `ValueID`. When I search for DataType of `ValueID` in I found it was `short`(Int16) and here I define class property with Int32 hence `SelectedValue` not getting set for class property `ID`. Thanks for pointing my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your class to use an `int` instead of a `long`:

```
public class BindingClass
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Code { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Your anonymous linq is most likely interpreting the value as an integer, not a long, and it's interfering with the DataBinding engine.

Comment: I tried this also but this not working. Problem not in binding its when selectedValue gets change for comboBox.

Comment: @AnkushMadankar This was the only way I could reproduce the problem and solve it.  You mention `display text set to empty`.  Do you have other databindings involved?

Comment: but I yet dont get solution, no there nothing else dataBinding involved in this code. When I did binding with SelectedIndex then its work properly

Comment: @AnkushMadankar Is the user changing the value of the ComboBox by selecting the drop down and selecting the row?  Or are you trying to do it the other way around, where you set the _bindingClass.ID value and you are expecting the ComboBox to update itself?

Comment: yes user changing value in comboBox by selecting  drop down. I am not setting value of bindingClass.ID any where in class expecting added binding change it itself. Do we need to pas any default value for bindingClass.ID? When I debbuge it, value for bindingClass.ID get set properly only text not displying in text area of comboBox

Comment: @AnkushMadankar Have you tried casting the ValueID from your data source to a long - `ValueMember = Convert.ToInt64(_row["ValueID"]),` ?

Comment: Actually I mention `ValueID` is of `int` but when I search for same in DataBase it was `Int16`, sorry for my mistake. Then accourding to complete senario `ID` property in `BindingClass` should `Int16` when I change it then I get desire output. Thanku for support. Please change your answer accourding to it.

Answer (score 1):

The basic issue here is that the SelectedValue property on your combo box will be of type BindingClass, and you are trying to persist it to an integer field.

I would take the SelectedValue placeholder object out of the BindingClass type - it makes no sense to try to store the value here anyway.  Instead, store it in your forms code-behind, or better yet, if you are using MVVM store it in your ViewModel.

```
Public class MyViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<BindingClass> { get; set; }       
    public BindingClass SelectedBindingClass {get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How to use `MyViewModel` for binding?

Answer (score 1):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindingList<BindingClass> list = new BindingList<BindingClass>();
        list.Add(new BindingClass { ID = 1, Name = "bc1" });
        list.Add(new BindingClass { ID = 2, Name = "bc2" });
        list.Add(new BindingClass { ID = 3, Name = "bc3" });
        comboBox1.DataSource = list;

        // If you want bind to class use this code. Selected property will contain BindingClass instance, selected in combobox
        //comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
        //comboBox1.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", this, "Selected", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);

        // Use label to view Selected value
        //label1.DataBindings.Add("Text", this, "Selected", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);

        // OR

        // If you want bind to ID use this code. SelectedId property of the form will contain ID value, selected in combobox
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "ID";
        comboBox1.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", this, "SelectedId", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);

        // Use label to view SelectedId value
        label1.DataBindings.Add("Text", this, "SelectedId", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
    }

    public BindingClass Selected { get; set; }

    public int SelectedId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Actually I already have binded comboBox with DisplayMember as string and ValueMember as int, so here I dont want to bind `list` with comboBox.

Comment: As I understand, you want to bind "SelectedValue" property of combobox to some property of you class? This is the main goal of Binding class, that you try to use in your question.

Comment: So, in my example this goal is achieved. I'll try to explain, line-by-line:
1. comboBox1.DataSource = list; -- here we set data source for combobox
2. comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name" -- here we set, what would be displayed in combobox for user. What property of your class BindingClass
3. comboBox1.ValueMember = "ID"; -- here we set, what property of BindingClass will be stored in SelectedValue property of combobox. If it empty, the whole BindingClass instance would be stored.

Comment: 4. comboBox1.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", this, "SelectedId", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged); -- this line bind SelectedValue property of compobox with SelectedId property of form, passed as source for binding.
So what do you need?

Comment: check now..Which will give u exact idea about What I exactly what.

Comment: What behavior do you expect? Please, write scenario

Comment: I wanna very simple behaviour from this code, as I change element from combobox or by user then selectedValue of comboBox must set in ID field of bindingClass object

Comment: Ensure, that BindingClass instance is already created when you create binding and also try this change:
var _dataSource = (from DataRow _row in _tableSource.Rows
                           select new
                           {
                               ValueMember = (long)_row["ValueID"],
                               DisplayMember = _row["ValueName"].ToString()

                           }).ToList();

Comment: Yes I declare and initiate _bindingClass object globally. Otherwise accessing same object would throw NullReferenceException!

Comment: Does your combobox work correct without bindings? I.e. debug in SelectedValueChanged event, what value does SelectedValue property have. And also try to explicit cast (long)_row["ValueID"], when fill your _dataSource

Comment: Yes I check it, every thing works fine. I am getting value for selectedValue on selectedIndex change event.